# PowerShell Install-Module Local vs CurrentUser

Tags: powershell, module, console

Could someone explain this please?

```
Import-Module PSReadLine -Scope CurrentUser

Import-Module : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Scope'.
The argument "CurrentUser" does not belong to the set "Local,Global"
specified by the ValidateSet attribute. Supply an argument that is in the
set and then try the command again.
At line:1 char:37
+     Import-Module PSReadLine -Scope CurrentUser
+                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Import-Module], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

But this works fine(!)

```
Install-Module PSScriptAnalyzer -Scope CurrentUser
```

And this works fine(!)

```
Import-Module PSReadLine -Scope Local
```

The help file for `Install-Module` doesn't even recognise the existence of `Local|Global` mentioned in the error. `-Scope <String> Specifies the installation scope of the module. The acceptable values for this parameter are AllUsers and CurrentUser.`

Comment: Install-Module installs the necessary files to your computer to run/load the module. Either to your profile path or to the program files folder. Import-Module loads an available module to the currently running instance of Powershell. One copies files the other runs the files.  ;-)

Comment: Got it, I've been mixing up the Cmdlets. My bad, thanks Olaf. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

These *scopes* differ substantially (excerpted from official *learn.microsoft.com*):

**[Import-Module -Scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module)**

> Specifies a [**scope** into which this cmdlet imports the module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes).
>
> The acceptable values for this parameter are:
>
> **Global**. Available to all commands in the session. Equivalent to the Global parameter.
>
> **Local**. Available only in the current scope.
>
> By default, when Import-Module cmdlet is called from the command
>   prompt, script file, or scriptblock, all the commands are imported
>   into the global session state. You can use the -Scope parameter with
>   the value of Local to import module content into the script or
>   scriptblock scope.
>
> When invoked from another module, Import-Module cmdlet imports the
>   commands in a module, including commands from nested modules, into the
>   caller's session state. Specifying -Scope Global or -Global indicates
>   that this cmdlet imports modules into the global session state so they
>   are available to all commands in the session.

**[Install-Module -Scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/install-module)**

> Specifies the **installation scope** of the module. The acceptable
>   values for this parameter are *AllUsers* and *CurrentUser*.
>
> The **AllUsers** scope installs modules in a location that is
>   accessible to all users of the computer:
>
> ```
> $env:ProgramFiles\PowerShell\Modules
> ```
>
> The **CurrentUser** installs modules in a location that is accessible
>   only to the current user of the computer:
>
> ```
> $home\Documents\PowerShell\Modules
> ```
>
> When no Scope is defined, the default is set based on the
>   PowerShellGet version.
>
> - In PowerShellGet versions 2.0.0 and above, the default is CurrentUser, which does not require elevation for install.
> - In PowerShellGet 1.x versions, the default is AllUsers, which requires elevation for install.

Comment: Oh no, I've been getting the two Cmdlets mixed up haven't I <doh>! Thanks @JosefZ, not my best post on here, but I'm probably not the only person to get confused over this so maybe it helps someone else hopefully... :-(

Answer (score 0):

For me and those who face similar issue, I had to add curly brackets "{}" around CurrentUser. Else nothing happened.

Example: Install-Module -Name SimplySql -Scope {CurrentUser}