# Alternate for Export-Excel

Tags: powershell

Below is the code where i am using Export-Excel to create a excel workbook where based on each service name there will be worksheet which will be created

```
$Hash = [ordered]@{"Server Name"="$ServerName";"Service Name"="$ServiceName";"Time(GMT)"="$GMTTime";"Time(EPOCH)"="$FEpoch"}
              foreach ($Property in $Properties) {
                  $Hash[$Property] = (($BlockData.$Property | Measure -Sum).Sum)/$blockvalue
                  }
   
   [pscustomobject]$Hash | Export-Excel "C:\script\Final_Report.xlsx" -WorksheetName $ServiceName -Append
```

But now the server where i have to execute the code needs admin access to install **ImportExcel** module in order to get the export-excel cmdlet.

Need idea on any alternate for doing this.

Comment: What module has to be installed?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that .updated the question with the module name.

Comment: Why not export to CSV and that can be opened with excel?

Comment: Any updates? Were you able to fix this?

Comment: Not able to fix this. somehow managed to install the ImportExcel module with admin credentials to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

> But now the server where i have to execute the code needs admin access
> to install ImportExcel module in order to get the export-excel cmdlet.

This is not completely accurate. You can specify the scope to install the module in.

```
Install-Module importexcle -Scope currentuser
```

See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60250339/4085331) for a nice explanation.

Comment: Tried this but getting error
**WARNING: Unable to download from URI 'https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=627338&clcid=0x409' to ''.
WARNING: Unable to download the list of available providers. Check your internet connection.
PackageManagement\Install-PackageProvider : No match was found for the specified search criteria for the provider 'NuGet'. The package provider requires 
'PackageManagement' and 'Provider' tags. Please check if the specified package has the tags.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1**
Internet is working fine.

Comment: Perhaps you can create a new question for the new issue